# Query specific for data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have my data in the following format

```
ITEMNO     Fes    Year      Funds     
1938331    LF     2016      334
1938331    LF     2016      123
1938331    LF     2017      234
1938331    SL     2016      099
1938331    SL     2017      080
1938331    SL     2017      741
1938331    SL     2018       41
```

I want my output in the following format

```
ITEMNO    FES     S(2016)   S(2017)   S(2018)
1938331   LF      334+123   234         0
1938331   SL      099       080+741     41
```

This is the sample data setup:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ITEMNO INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Fes    VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
  ,Year   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Funds  VARCHAR(3)  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'LF',2016,'334');
INSERT INTO mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'LF',2016,'123');
INSERT INTO mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'LF',2017,'234');
INSERT INTO mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'SL',2016,'099');
INSERT INTO mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'SL',2017,'080');
INSERT INTO mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'SL',2017,'741');
INSERT INTO mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'SL',2018,'41');
```

Please help me on how to write down the query

Comment: What queries have you tried? Hint: look into `GROUP BY`.

Comment: you want a `PIVOT TABLE`

Comment: I have gone on and assumed that the `Funds` column is of type `VARCHAR`. If that is not the case, please let me know. In my answer I also took your expected output literally, i.e. the result concatenates the `Funds` with `+` in between. If that is not the case, please consult the answer given by scsimon.

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you the expected result, dynamically (i.e., for any number of years that appear in your source table). You'll see that to do this, you need quite a few complex constructs. That's why people often say (with right) that T-SQL is not the right language to do this in. But if you really need to do this in T-SQL, here goes:

---

```sql
CREATE TABLE #mytable(
   ITEMNO INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Fes    VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
  ,Year   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Funds  INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'LF',2016,'334');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'LF',2016,'123');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'LF',2017,'234');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'SL',2016,'099');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'SL',2017,'080');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'SL',2017,'741');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ITEMNO,Fes,Year,Funds) VALUES (1938331,'SL',2018,'41');

DECLARE @piv_cols NVARCHAR(MAX)=STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',[S('+CAST(year AS VARCHAR)+')]'
    FROM #mytable
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'');
DECLARE @sel_cols NVARCHAR(MAX)=STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',[S('+CAST(year AS VARCHAR)+')]=ISNULL([S('+CAST(year AS VARCHAR)+')],''0'')'
    FROM #mytable
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'');

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'
SELECT
    p.itemno,p.fes,'+@sel_cols+N'
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ITEMNO,
            fes,
            q_year=''S(''+CAST(year AS VARCHAR)+'')'',
            Funds
        FROM
            #mytable
    ) AS bt
    PIVOT(
        SUM(Funds) FOR q_year IN ('+@piv_cols+')
    ) AS p
';

EXECUTE (@sql);
DROP TABLE #mytable;
```

Result is:

```
╔═════════╦═════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ itemno  ║ fes ║ S(2016) ║ S(2017) ║ S(2018) ║
╠═════════╬═════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ 1938331 ║ LF  ║     457 ║     234 ║       0 ║
║ 1938331 ║ SL  ║      99 ║     821 ║      41 ║
╚═════════╩═════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: I would want the output of 334+123=457 and similar .Please help

Comment: @Madhav Scsimon's answer didn't help you?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need [Dynamic SQL with a PIVOT](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/):

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME([Year])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Year] FROM mytable) AS [Year]

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ITEMNO, Fes, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM mytable
    PIVOT(SUM(cast(Funds as int)) 
          FOR [Year] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: I supplied the sample data in the question, I think I mistakenly took Funds to be an INT instead of VARCHAR... Seeing as the expected output retains the `0` for certain funds.

Comment: Funds is an `INT` in the DDL provided by the OP. I think they listed the actual math equation just to show what should be applied there. Not the best way to list expected results i agree.

Comment: I put the DDL there, sorries

Comment: what i mean is i don't think they want ###+### but rather the evaluation of this equation. I guess we will find out if the OP comments.

Comment: Oh I see what you did now... this still applies but you may have edited incorrectly i see. One of ours will work, depending on what they want.

Comment: If the OP responds... he has two options to choose from now with both our answers. I am still confused, but I took the OP's question literally.

Comment: I need the evaluation of the equation